# Tomcat catalina.out logrotate on redhat not working properly

Tags: linux, redhat, catalina, logrotate

I am trying to roll the log catalina.out on a webserver using logrotate.
I have been able to roll the log and a log `catalina.out-dateext` is created.
But I notice that the log is being written in the new file `catalina.out-dateext`.
Is there something that need to be done on the webserver?

Thank you

Comment: what have you written in /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat, what I feel is you want to say that current log is being written to catalina.out-datext and also to catalina.out or not.

Comment: hi,

/home/Tomcat/logs/catalina.out {  
    daily
    rotate 7
    missingok
    create 0644 tomcat tomcat
 dateext
}

i did not put the file in  /etc/logrotate.d/
instead i put the file in another directory and then from java i execute the commad: /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/pex/tomcat
the log is rolled to catalina.out-20130919
and catalina.out is 0kb.
but the log is being written to the catalina.out-20130919 instead of catalina.out.

Comment: Use copytruncate option – truncates the original log file in place after creating a copy, instead of moving the old log file and optionally creating a new one, It can be used when some program can not be told to close its logfile and thus might continue writing (appending) to the previous log file.

Comment: add copytruncate in your /etc/pex/tomcat file.For more info about all the options http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2010/03/howto-rotate-tomcat-catalina-out/

Comment: Thank you...
it worked.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: Hi can you please upvote my comment then :) if it worked for you. adding as an answer might be helpful for anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `copytruncate` in your `/etc/pex/tomcat` file. For more info about all the options: [vineetmanohar.com/2010/03/howto-rotate-tomcat-catalina-out](http://vineetmanohar.com/2010/03/howto-rotate-tomcat-catalina-out)